# nodejs for loop logic for random print

Tags: node.js, random

i have a for loop, inside that loop i have to print 160 messages, 62 times each message, but randomly

like:

message 1
message 6
message 178
message 1
message 3789
message 1
...

i thought to use inside the for 160 if statement like

```
for(int i = 0; i<9920; i++){
  if(i<=62){
    print message
  }else if(i>63 && i<=124){
    print message
  }
....
}
```

but i don't know if it's the better solution and i don't know how to make it random

someone can help me?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+random

Comment: It's impossible to tell what you want to do from your question and code :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to understand your question. If I parsed your text correctly, what you want is to print every message 62 times but randomly (instead of fixed a sequence).

I'm using a while loop, that is of course doable with any looping construct.

```js
let totalPrintedMessages = 0;
const printedMessageCount = {};
const messages = []; //["Message 1", "Message 2", "Message 3", "Message 4"];
for (let i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
  messages.push("Message " + i);
}

while (true) {
  // once we're done printing each message(s) 62 times randomly
  if (totalPrintedMessages === messages.length * 62) break;

  //using a count variable is more efficent
  // if (isDone()) break;

  // picking a message randomly from the list & printing it
  const toPrint =
    messages[parseInt(Math.floor(Math.random() * messages.length))];
  // skipping if already printed 62 times
  if (printedMessageCount[toPrint] === 62) {
    continue;
  }
  totalPrintedMessages++;
  console.log(toPrint);

  // individual print count(s)
  if (!printedMessageCount[toPrint]) {
    printedMessageCount[toPrint] = 1;
  } else {
    printedMessageCount[toPrint]++;
  }

  // checking the current state of printed messages
  // console.log(printedMessageCount);
}

function isDone() {
  let printed = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
    if (printedMessageCount[messages[i]] === 62) printed++;
  }
  return printed === messages.length;
}
```